# Comparing frequency differences to period differences

Tags: physics

I have two signals. One has a frequency of $10$ Hz, the other has a frequency of $5$ Hz.

Or, in other words, one has a period of $\dfrac 1{10}$ seconds, and the other has a $\dfrac 15$ seconds.

The difference in their frequencies is $10 Hz - 5 Hz = 5 Hz$.

The difference in their periods is $\dfrac 1{10} - \dfrac 15 = -0.1$ seconds.

But $\dfrac 15 Hz$ = $2$ seconds $!= -0.1$ seconds.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: $$1/a - 1/b \ne 1 / (a - b)$$ so why would you *expect* them to be the same?

Comment: @user296602 Yes I see that. But shouldn't the differences be somehow relatable, since they are expressed in complementary units (seconds and Hz)?

Comment: The are related, through the correct equality $1/a - 1/b = (b - a) / (ab)$, which has the same units as $1 / (a - b)$.

Comment: So to put things differently, if I know (only) the difference in frequency, I don't necessarily know the difference in period?

Comment: Yes. Think about specific examples: What is the difference in period between 1 Hz and 2 Hz? What is the difference in period between 100 Hz and 101 Hz? Are they the same?

Comment: The _difference_ in the frequencies or periods really has no actual relevance to anything - what matters is the _ratio_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed by [MalayTheDynamo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2672570/505767) note that since

$$f=\frac1T \implies f_2-f_1=\frac1{T_2}-\frac1{T_1}=\frac{T_1-T_2}{T_2T_1}$$

thus

$$10 Hz-5Hz =5Hz = \frac{0.20-0.10}{0.20\cdot 0.10}=\frac{0.10}{0.02}= 5 Hz$$

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that $\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac1{a+b}$. This is true.

What you want is to add, then multiply by product.

$$\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac{a+b}{ab}$$

You're making an elementary mistake, and this is usual. Don't worry, you'll get better rapidly with time.